# In laravel how to count table valve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

[image]I want to count each center users how mach student they registered.

I have two different table, `center` and `student`

In first table `Center`, I have c`enter_id` column. In that table I have center_id like "PP_123".

In second table `student` I was created `center_code` column. In that table I am saving center_code like "PP_123".

If center user registers student that time second table `student` files with student data along with it stores the `center_code` in `student` table.

**center table data ALL CENTERS LIST**

```
      scenter_name                Date of join      center_code
    HALO  COMPUTERS                02-12-2019         PP_123

         scenter_name             Date of join      center_code
    SKILL EDUCATION CENTER         02-12-2019         PP_123
```

**student table data ALL REGISTERED STUDENT LIST**

```
student_name student_f_name student_m_name center_code
    abc           abc           abc         PP_123

student_name student_f_name student_m_name center_code
    xyz           xyz           xyz         PP_123

student_name student_f_name student_m_name center_code
        vvv           vvv           vvv         PP_124
```

**view should show result like below**

```
CENTER CODE       DATE OF JOIN       CENTER NAME         APPLICATION COUNT
  PP_123           02-12-2019      HALO  COMPUTERS            2
  PP_124           10-12-2019    SKILL EDUCATION CENTER       1
```

**Controller** [This code only showing all centers name and id]

```
public function center_activities()
{
    $activities_list = 
    return view('Center.cernter_activites',compact('activities_list'));
}
```

**my view**

```
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>SL,no</th>
                                
                                         
                                            <th>CENTER CODE</th>
                                          <th>DATE OF JOIN</th>
                                            <th>CENTER NAME</th>
                                            <th> APPLICATION count</th>
                                            
                                           
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>
                      
                                        <tr >
                                            <td>{{ $key + 1  }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $activities_list->center_code }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $activities_list->center_join_date }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $activities_list->center_name }}</td>
                                             <td>0</td>
                                            

                                        </tr>
                                       
                                  
                                        </tbody>
                      
                                    </table>
```

**my model with relationship one to one**

Center.php model

```
    public function student()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Student', 'center_code');
}
```

Student.php model

```
 public function center()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Center', 'center_code');
    }
```

Comment: do you have the relationship setup between these models?

Comment: @lagbox question updated

Comment: still not sure what you are trying to count since this is a one to one relationship, is there a field on one of these tables with a count? if there was a one to many, i could see needing to do a count

Comment: @lagbox question updated

Comment: so the relationship should be a one to many .. student belongs to center and center has many student, but based on center_code not the 'id' of the center ?

Comment: @lagbox  yes your right

Comment: @lagbox how to code to get my accepted result please tell me

Comment: @lagbox  i need your help to get result i am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get a count of all the students for the centers you are searching for, you should be able to use `withCount` to get a count of the related records for each center. Try setting up things as below:

Center Model:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Student::class, 'center_code', 'center_code');
}
```

Controller:

```
$centers = Center::where('center_delete', 'NOT-DELETED')
    ->where('account_type', 'OLD_ACCOUNT')
    ->withCount('students')
    ->get();
```

View:

```
@foreach ($centers as $center)
    ...
    <td>{{ $center->students_count }}</td>
    ...
@endforeach
```

[Laravel 5.7 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Counting Related Records](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) `withCount`